# How to get the output of subprocess.check_output() python module?

Tags: python, windows, string, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm trying to get information from a Command Prompt (CMD - Windows ) in python, using the module subprocess like this :

```
ipconfig = subprocess.check_output("ipconfig")
print(ipconfig)
```

The result is:

```
b'\r\nWindows IP Configuration\r\n\r\n\r\nEthernet adapter Local Area Connect:\r\n\r\n   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : XX.XXX\r\n   IPv4 address. . . . . . . . . . . : XXXXXXXXX\r\n   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : XXXXXXXXXX\r\n   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : XXXXXX\r\n'
```

I've read the documentation on `module subprocess` but I didn't find anything that fits my problem.

I need this information in a nice formatted string ... not like that, what could I do?

(I Think the problem here is a string format, but if you have tips for getting a nice output without needing of string formatting, I appreciate)

I know that I can get IP address with socket module, but I'm just giving an example.

Comment: What kind of "nice formatting" do you want? What you have there is the literal output of `ipconfig`, which is formatted, to start with...

Comment: The one which @martijn answered, the 'real' result of prompt.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are printing a `bytes` string value, and `print()` turned that into a unicode string using `repr()`. You want to decode the value to unicode instead:

```
import sys

print(ipconfig.decode(sys.stdout.encoding))
```

This uses the encoding of the console to interpret the command output.

Comment: Wow! That works perfectly, I will stude the decode,stdout,encoding methods ... Thank you very much

Comment: Why did you prefer `sys.stdout.encoding` over `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` ? `sys.stdout` *can* be `None` in some cases.

Comment: @Kentzo: `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` is the wrong codec; your file system and your terminal do not have to use the same encoding..