# Getting codepage / encoding for windows executables called with subprocess.check_output from python

Tags: python, windows, character-encoding, subprocess

I have a similar issue to [How to get the output of subprocess.check_output() python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486703/how-to-get-the-output-of-subprocess-check-output-python-module) but the solution there does not work for German Windows.

I execute the following script in python 3.10 in wsl2 / ubuntu:

```py
import subprocess
import sys

ipconfig = subprocess.check_output(["ipconfig.exe", "/all"]).decode(sys.stdout.encoding)
```

This leads to

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x84 in position 90: invalid start byte
```

The bytes returned from `check_output` are:

```
b'\r\nWindows-IP-Konfiguration\r\n\r\n   Hostname  . . . . . . . . . . . . : XXXXXXXXXXXX\r\n   Prim\x84res DNS-Suffix .
```

and `sys.stdout.encoding` is `utf-8`. But this is wrong, as `\x84` is invalid under utf-8.

The `\x84` here is an `ä`. According to https://tripleee.github.io/8bit/#84 this corresponds to e.g. `cp850` for western european encoding, which makes sense.

How can I get the correct encoding programmatically?

Comment: What does `locale.getpreferredencoding()` give you? Hopefully that should give you the normal encoding for your Windows install (as opposed to `sys.stdout.encoding`, which is specifically what Python uses when writing to stdout).

Comment: Sadly, also UTF-8 in python on WSL. Python on windows produces `cp1252` which is wrong, too, as `\x84` is `„` not `ä` for `cp1252`.

Comment: `LookupError: unknown encoding: oem` when called from WSL (calling from windows works, but the script needs to run in WSL)

Comment: `ipconfig = subprocess.check_output(["ipconfig.exe", "/all"], encoding="cp850")`

Comment: That works for my computer, but I want a solution how to get the correct encoding programatically, and not hardcode `cp850`.